# how to use Regex in password box in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, wpf, passwordbox

I wanted to test my input password in password box in WPF so that its only
aplhabets, digits and special characters.. I did the following code bt the loop is directly going to Else Loop. What should I do for its proper functioning?

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^(?=.+[A-Za-z])(?=.+\\d)(?=.+[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$");
if (regex.IsMatch(txtPassword.ToString()))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Correctly");   
}
else
{
    txtPassword.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("Password should contain atleast one alphabet,number & special character");
}
```

Comment: Clearly you're not getting  a match - your regex isnt doing what you think it is

Comment: what is type of `txtPassword?`

Comment: if it's `TextBox` use `txtPassword.Text` instead of 'txtPassword.ToString()`

Comment: txtPassword is my password box in WPF.

Apparently you cannot use txtpassword.Text in case of password boxes.That is the reason I'm using .toString()

Comment: Hey @SeM txtPassword is a paasword box not a textbox. there's no .text available for this. 
Also I'm currently unaware why regex is not able to apply on this

Comment: Hey @BugFinder I'm not sure why my regex is not working. Do u know of any improvisations I can apply here ?

Comment: Then use `txtPassword.Password` instead of this.

Comment: Hey @SeM.. thnx dude..its done now :D

Comment: Let me put it on answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `txtPassword.Password` instead of `txtPassword.ToString()`.

Good luck on your project :)

Answer (score 0):

[`txtPassword.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is giving a string representation of the textbox..

This should be [`txtPassword.Password`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Note: using [`SecurePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better option but I haven't had chance to test this with the regex check.

Comment: @beginner_coder no worries if you get chance try using secure password instead there's a note in the docs I linked stating that would be preferred